# missing ) after argument list Just when I call one function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a weird behavior, when I have call this function `$blockProduct` in my js part, I will have this error `missing ) after argument list` but when I change that function with another `$blockService`, I don't have the error anymore !

**php:**

```
$blockService= $blockObject->getPaymentmethodOptionArray();
```

return:

```
array(5) {
  [0] => array(2) {
    ["value"] => string(1) "1"
    ["label"] => string(2) "CB"
  }
  [1] => array(2) {
    ["value"] => string(1) "3"
    ["label"] => string(4) "Visa"
  }
}
```

```
$blockProduct = $blockObject->getProductOptionArray();
```

return:

```
array(3) {
  [0] => array(2) {
    ["value"] => string(1) "1"
    ["label"] => string(14) "Bidon d'huile"
  }
}
```

I think the problem comes from `é` ?

**JS:**

```
jQuery(InputsWrapper3).append(
                    '<div class="added">' +
                        '<select id="produit_option_'+ FieldCount +'"'+ 'class="select" name="produit_option[]">'+
                        '<?php foreach($blockProduct as $prod):?>'+ /*$blockProduit*/
                            '<option value="<?php echo $prod['value']; ?>" selected><?php echo $prod['label']; ?></option>'+
                        '<?php endforeach; ?>'+
                        '</select>' +
                        '<input type="text" name="produit_input[]" id="produit_field_'+ FieldCount3 +'"/>' +
                        ' <a href="#" class="removeclass">'+deleteIcon+'</a>' +
                    '</div>'
                );
```

Comment: Unless that JavaScript is actually in a php file, this won't do what you expect it to do.

Comment: `$blockProduct = $blockObject->getProductOptionArray()` is missing a `;`

Comment: No, in phtml file so I can put the both, this is not the problem, I have another block `InputsWrapper2` before with `$blockService` and it works fine

Comment: @kerbholz sorry I forgot when I copied my code but they are in my file, updated thanks

Comment: Build the HTML in a variable, then console log it. Then just put the variable in the append. Easier to troubleshoot that way. so like var html = '<div>....' html += 'next stuff etc.

Comment: If you think the error comes from that `é`, have you tried running the code without it?

Comment: Firstly, is that `PHP` script with JQuery working ?

Comment: Guys, I confirm it is the the `'` that causes problem in `["label"] => string(14) "Bidons d'huile"` I updated it to `"Bidons dhuile"` and have no more the error Is there a trick for that ? escaping it for exemple ?

Comment: Try using  this   \'  ==> Bidons d\'huile

Comment: Where in data base ? no I can't do that, rather somthing in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use php escape character method 
e.g in you case    htmlspecialchars($prod['value'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

Comment: `$prod['label']` instead, and it works, please add this piece of code in the precedent answer, then I accept it

Comment: Thanks for your time